# Vuetify help: how to fix native custom element compilerOptions.isCustomElement error

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3, vuetify-datatable

It's my first time using Vuetify and I am trying to create a v-data-table. I've created a Vuetify project following the instruccions on the [Vuetify docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/). Once it was done creating,I wanted to test out how it worked so I copied to code of one of the table components, specifically the one that uses CRUD: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/basics/

When I try to preview it, nothing renders and I get this error in the console:
HelloWorld.vue:114 [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: v-data-table
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement.
`at <HelloWorld>  at <VMain>  at <VApp>  at <App>`

It would seem that I haven't installed Vuetify correctly, but I checked and it is correctly installed in my plugins folder, inside the index.js file so I should be able to use the Vuetify components without having to import them anywhere.

Has anyone else encountered this issue and how did you solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Data tables in v3 are still in development, you have to specifically add them from [labs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/labs/introduction/)